# Trying to get pipeline status via api

Tags: azure, api, azure-data-factory

Currently I am trying to get data factory pipeline status through Azure management API but getting this error.
"Invoking Web Activity failed with HttpStatusCode - '405 : MethodNotAllowed', message - ''"
Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using below sample request

**PipelineRuns_Get**

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/12345678-1234-1234-1234-12345678abc/resourceGroups/exampleResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/exampleFactoryName/pipelineruns/2f7fdb90-5df1-4b8e-ac2f-064cfa58202b?api-version=2018-06-01
```

Sample Response

Status code:

200

```
Date: XXX
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
x-ms-ratelimit-remaining-subscription-reads: 14988
x-ms-request-id: 6d9de9bd-a412-4a6f-8b9e-37d369323646
x-ms-correlation-request-id: 6d9de9bd-a412-4a6f-8b9e-37d369323646
```

Response Body

```
{
  "runId": "2f7fdb90-5df1-4b8e-ac2f-064cfa58202b",
  "pipelineName": "examplePipeline",
  "parameters": {
    "OutputBlobNameList": "[\"exampleoutput.csv\"]"
  },
  "invokedBy": {
    "id": "80a01654a9d34ad18b3fcac5d5d76b67",
    "name": "Manual"
  },
  "runStart": "2018-06-16T00:37:44.6257014Z",
  "runEnd": "2018-06-16T00:38:12.7314495Z",
  "durationInMs": 28105,
  "status": "Succeeded",
  "message": "",
  "lastUpdated": "2018-06-16T00:38:12.7314495Z",
  "annotations": []
}
```

For more information follow this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/pipeline-runs/get#pipelineruns_get)